# Excel copy from cell to clipboard

Tags: excel, clipboard, vba

In Excel 2013 into cell i post this string

```
'<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
```

Then i copying this cell to clipboard using ctrl+c and post to notepad using ctrl+v I get this

```
"<xml xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">'
"
```

So all my string became quoted and trimed first single quote, also added additional quotes to url, how to prevent changes and get string as it is.

[image]

Comment: Copy/paste or keyed or get from VBA does no matter, result the same

Comment: Yes but it is no change anything i tryed trim newline and the same

Comment: Maybe you right man, so how to trim them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68347/discussion-between-dmitrij-holkin-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel identifies the first `'` as Symbol that the value in a cell is text.

And are you sure it is doubling the `"` when pasting it into notepad?

Comment: Yes I'm shure! you can test by yourself

Comment: yaa i have tested it and it didn't actually doubled the `"` only problem was that first single quote was missing which is natural in case of Excel

Comment: YOU MUST BE DOING IT IN vba I GUESS

Comment: I do this in VBA also and result is the same

Comment: DO `cell.PrefixCharacter & cell.Value` to get the proper string in VBA